# JavaScript object literal nested object state

Tags: javascript

I try to call "ViewModel.healthData.get" twice. In both cases, the method retrieves the data from the Internet. How can I make the "data" field retain its data?

```
function MyObject() {
    this.ViewModel.healthData.get(this.ViewModel.healthData.set);
}
MyObject.prototype = {
    ViewModel: {
        healthData: {
            data: null,
            set: function (result) {
                console.log("data from set");
                this.data = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
            },
            get: function (callback) {
                if (this.data === null) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/Health",
                        type: 'GET',
                        async: true,
                    }).done(callback);
                } else {
                    console.log("direct data");
                    return this.data;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow, thats a bit convoluted. Its unclear what exactly wpould be going wrong here. On top of that, why does the assignment to `this.data` not simply happen in the getter? It would solve all your issues (apart from the fact that this is asynchronous - to solve that, have a look at `Promises` to return a value than will be filled in once resolved)

Comment: ...cache it? Sth like `$.ajax(...).done(data => this.data = data).done(callback)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to have a look at Promises for this, it will simplify your workflow a lot. Since you are *waiting* for data to be populated, your calls could happen too soon or too late, but with promises that's not the case. Simply call `resolve` when done (or `reject` when failed) and pass it the data you received. From then on any function called with `.then` (and any function called that way since starting the request) will be called immediately with the data in the first argument.

```
function MyObject() {
    this.ViewModel.healthData = new Promise(function( resolve, reject ){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/Health",
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
        }).done(function(data){ 
             resolve(ko.mapping.fromJS(result))
        }).fail( reject )
    });
}
MyObject.prototype = { ViewModel: { healthData: null } };
```

When you create a new `MyObject` here, it will automatically instantiate the required data inside a promise. To Access and use the data, simple use:

```
myInstanceOfMyObject.ViewModel.healthData.then(function(data){
    // Do whatever you want with the passed data here
});
```

This will resolve some of your asynchronous woes and highly simplify the structure.